# ElasticSearch - Exact whole words matching for Equal to operations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am looking for a way to get the result by matching **EXACT WHOLE WORDS** from Elasticsearch. This is for "EQ" ("=") operations from UI.

```
{
    "_index": "docs",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "DocId": 1,
        "DocDate": "2020-07-24T10:16:44.0000000Z",
        "Conversation": "I just need to know how frequently I should remind you"
    }
},
{
    "_index": "docs",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "DocId": 2,
        "DocDate": "2020-07-25T10:16:45.0000000Z",
        "Conversation": "Building a work culture in your firm"
    }
}
```

in here, when querying with "I just need to know how frequently I should remind you" for Conversation, then only ES should return DocId 1 data.
Even the query is like "I just need to know how frequently I should remind", then it should return empty.

I tried these ES queries, but not able to figure it out.

```
GET docs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match_phrase": {
          "Conversation": "just need to know"
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}

GET docs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "Conversation",
      "query": "\"just need to know\""
    }
  }
}

GET docs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "Conversation": {"query": "just need to know",
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `.keyword` to the `Conversation` field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after the `Conversation` field).

When using standard analyzer

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "I just need to know how frequently I should remind you"
}
```

The following tokens are generated :

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "i",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 1,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "just",
      "start_offset": 2,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "need",
      "start_offset": 7,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "to",
      "start_offset": 12,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "know",
      "start_offset": 15,
      "end_offset": 19,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 4
    },
    {
      "token": "how",
      "start_offset": 20,
      "end_offset": 23,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 5
    },
    {
      "token": "frequently",
      "start_offset": 24,
      "end_offset": 34,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 6
    },
    {
      "token": "i",
      "start_offset": 35,
      "end_offset": 36,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 7
    },
    {
      "token": "should",
      "start_offset": 37,
      "end_offset": 43,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 8
    },
    {
      "token": "remind",
      "start_offset": 44,
      "end_offset": 50,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 9
    },
    {
      "token": "you",
      "start_offset": 51,
      "end_offset": 54,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

**Whereas the keyword analyzer returns the entire input string as a single token.**
If you have not defined any explicit mapping, then your modified search query will be :

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Conversation.keyword": "I just need to know how frequently I should remind you"
    }
  }
}
```

You can even change your index mapping, in the following way :

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Conversation": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if the Conversation field is having around 10,000 words, even this situation, shall we use as a keyword field?

Comment: @MahadevanG The .keyword field takes the same input and keeps it as one large string. Even if you have a `Conversation` field of 10000 words, and you want to have an exact match (in such a way that the text should not be analyzed), then you have to use the `keyword` field data type OR you can even use keyword analyzer

Comment: Thanks, ESCoder. in our application, User can search with EQ ("=") operator & CO ("Contains") operator. CO ("Contains") operator for searching for a phrase in the Conversation field. So if we add the keyword field to the Conversation, then we could not use CO operator for a phrase search. Please suggest.

Comment: @MahadevanG Yes, if you are using only the `keyword` data type, you cannot do a phrase search. Can you please give some example that explains your use case?